# How do I prevent a for loop is overwriting my results

Tags: r

I would like to scrape all the seasons from 2003-2004 to 2019-2020 of the Dutch football league including the 34 playing rounds (I am using this website https://www.voetbal.com/wedstrijdgegevens/ned-eredivisie-2003-2004-spieltag/). As you can see in my code it's only showing me de results of de last season. I think it's overwriting the other seasons. What am I doing wrong? What do I have to add to my code? Can anybody help me?

Here is the code I use:

````
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(caret)
library(rvest)
library(devtools)
library(httr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
library(xml2)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

url <- sprintf("https://www.voetbal.com/wedstrijdgegevens/ned-eredivisie-%d-%d-spieltag/", 2003:2019, 2004:2020)

basis<-function(url){
  
  website <- read_html(url)
  
  Sys.sleep(2)
  
  datum <- website %>% 
    html_nodes(".data .standard_tabelle td[nowrap]:nth-of-type(1)") %>%
    html_text()
  
  tijdstip <- website %>% 
    html_nodes(".data .standard_tabelle td[nowrap]:nth-of-type(2)") %>%
    html_text()
  
  thuisclub <- website %>%
    html_nodes(".data .standard_tabelle [align='right'] a") %>%
    html_text()
  
  uitclub <- website %>%
    html_nodes(".standard_tabelle td:nth-of-type(5) a") %>%
    html_text()
  
  uitslag <- website %>%
    html_nodes(".data .standard_tabelle td[nowrap]:nth-of-type(6)") %>%
    html_text()
  
  return(tibble(datum=datum, tijdstip=tijdstip, thuisclub=thuisclub, uitclub=uitclub, uitslag=uitslag))
}

overige_seizoenen<-function(url){
  for (i in 1:17){
    
    list_of_pages<-str_c(url[[i]], 1:34)
    
    table <-list_of_pages%>%
      map(basis)%>%
      bind_rows()
    
    }
return(table)
}
  

jochem <- overige_seizoenen(url)
```
````

Comment: for loops always only save the latest entry. there are a couple of ways to circumvent it. one posibility would be to store/append every result to an external/global variable like an empty data.frame. you could also use the ready made package "magicfor" which saves every iteration of a for loop.

Comment: Simplify your example, do we need all of those packages?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is an error in the `for` loop. In R, if you want a loop to iterate from element 1 to 10, you can't just say `for (i in 10)`, you must clarify it as `for (i in 1:10)`. So try this loop now:

```
for (i in 1:seizoenen){
    
    list_of_pages<-str_c(url[[i]], 1:34)
    
    table <-list_of_pages%>%
      map(basis)%>%
      bind_rows()
    
    }
return(table)
}
```

Comment: my fault, "seizoenen" wasn't correct. In my code, there was standing 1:17. I changed it. But still, I only have the last result.